Witharrow-package: Can I make all arrows look the same?
I just recently discovered the "Witharrows-package" in latex and wrote a code which had this form:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {backgrounds,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{WithArrows}
A &= B+C \Arrow[tikz={-stealth, gray!80,thick,in = 100, out = 80, looseness=2}]{$B=D+E+F$}\\
  &= D+E+\underbrace{F+C}_{=0} \Arrow[tikz={-stealth, gray!80,thick,in = 100, out = 80, looseness=2}]{D+E = H}\\
  &= H
\end{WithArrows}
\end{align*}

\end{document}


Now the problem I am facing is, that the second arrow is much bigger than the first arrow due to the underbrace command which makes the line higher. Is there a way to make this arrow the same size as the first arrow?

Welcome to tex.sx.  I haven't tested this, but would decreasing the space between the second and third lines (using [-2\jot] or something similar after the \\ ) make a difference?

In case you'd like to keep the spacing, you could use something like looseness=1.2 for the second arrow to get a similar width.

Simply remove the looseness=2 parameter

@barbarabeeton Thank you, I tried your approach, but I don't think this works as the next line gets moved into the underbrace at some point.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Hi, I may have expressed what I want too vague. when I remove or reduce the looseness, the arrow with is reduced which is at least an improvement. But What I actually want is that the arrow looks exactly the same as the one above, regardless of the hight of the line.

@Physic_Student -- Obviously you're correct.  I was looking at your example, where the last line is very short.  Maybe useful in some cases then, if not all.

@barbarabeeton Oh I see, in the example I gave as minimal example it would work, unfortunately my expression is a little bit more ugly. So I will keep it in mind, thank you!
